# how to find similar word with more similarities

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

how to Find words with length less than or equal...

```
  declare @inp nvarchar(max),@data nvarchar(max)
  set @inp='You can dance, you can jive, having .... jove... jve, ...' 
  set @data = 'jeve'
  select @inp as results where @inp like '%' + @data +'%'
```

@inp not return any data, but i want show:

```
results 
=====
jive
jove
jve
```

Comment: Do you want a T-SQL solution, or a CLR solution (which would be [trivial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx))? Do you have to do this once (favour T-SQL), or many times (favour CLR)?

Comment: If @inp = 'You can dance, you can jive, having .... jove... jve, ...jeep, ...veej'  Would you want results results 
 = 
jive, jove, jve, jeep, veej
?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never thought of [SOUNDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) or [DIFFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) as that useful, and they are certainly a bit old-fashioned these days.  However we can combine it with the full-text parser, and it does in fact answer this query.  Note the extra quotes in the search statement:

```
DECLARE @inp NVARCHAR(MAX), @data NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @inp= '"You can dance, you can jive, having .... jove... jve, ..."' 
SET @data = 'jeve'

SELECT display_term, SOUNDEX(display_term) sdx
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@inp,0,0,0)
WHERE SOUNDEX(display_term) = SOUNDEX(@data)
 AND LEN(display_term) <= LEN(@data)

SELECT display_term, SOUNDEX(display_term) sdx, DIFFERENCE(display_term,@data) diff
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(@inp,0,0,0)
```

There is a fairly limited use case for these functions so if you have more complex examples then they probably won't extend.  Worth a mention though.

Comment: What would be the not olde fashioned way to do a sounds like query (soundex)? I coincidentally just learner out the algorithm that makes sounded work a couple of weeks ago and I was impressed...Maybe this would be a machine learning problem now?

Comment: I was thinking something like Levenshtein Distance or some kind of CLR pattern matching, or maybe SQL 2012 SEMANTICSIMILARITYTABLE.  It's not really clear what they're after.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is not T-SQL, but CLR and Regular Expressions.

[Here is an article to get your started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx)

If this is possible in pure T-SQL it will need more specific rules around what represents a match and what doesn't that your use case unfortunately did not specify.